# Oracle: show parameters on error

Tags: oracle, logging, parameters

When Oracle logs a parameterized SQL query failing, it shows "?" in place of the parameters, i.e. the query before replacing parameters. For example,

```
"SELECT * FROM table where col like '?'" 
SQL state [99999]; error code [29902]; 
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine ORA-20000: 
  Oracle Text error: DRG-50901: 
  text query parser syntax error on line 1, column 48
```

Is there a way to change logging so it shows the **parameter values**? The information above is absolutely useless unless I can see what the actual parsing problem was.

In general, is there a way to set logs in Oracle to show parameters in parameterized query errors?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Oracle 10g or later and you have access to the V$ views, then you can use  v$sql_bind_capture to see the values.

The following query is borrowed from Burleson's site:

```
SELECT 
   a.sql_text, 
   b.name, 
   b.position, 
   b.datatype_string, 
   b.value_string 
FROM
   v$sql_bind_capture b,
   v$sqlarea          a
WHERE
   b.sql_id = 'The SQL ID'
AND 
   b.sql_id = a.sql_id;
```